# WPF Semi-dynamic grid

Tags: c#, wpf, grid

I have a 2D array of LEDs I want to switch on / off.
For this, I want to use an grid and each cell should show a toggle button for switching.

The number of LEDs may vary, but is known at startup from a config file (no change in gridsize at runtime).

I saw some solutions for fully dynamic grids, but they seem ridicoulusly complicated for my needs.

Is there any way to create a grid with a template?

I also tried using a DataGrid, but this is also limited to 1D Arrays.

Usually (for stacking elements in one direction), I use something like

```
<StackPanel>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ArrayOfElementsToBindTo}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ViewTemplate}" />
</StackPanel>
```

Is there anything similiar possible for a 2D grid?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a [`UniformGrid`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.uniformgrid?view=netframework-4.8). You'll need to specify the number of columns (or rows), and the UniformGrid will work out the rows (or columns) from the number of elements.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ArrayOfElementsToBindTo}" ItemTemplate="...">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Columns="2" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

I think you can bind `Columns` to something (e.g. to `ArrayOfElementsToBindTo`, through a suitable converter), if you need to calculate it based on the number of items.